# BULK INSERT fails because of an access denial, despite having read permissions granted to the directory

Tags: sql-server, permissions

The SQL Server is log on as a domain user. It has **read** and **read & execute** permissions granted to the specific network directory (let's say `\\path_to_network_directory\`), which I have checked in two ways:

1. By mapping a network drive with user's credentials. It allowed me to enter the directory and read all files as I expected.
2. By restoring a database backup from the directory.

At this point I am quite sure that SQL Sever has access to the directory. Although I cannot bulk insert from a file that is located there.

But when I execute this

```
BULK INSERT TEST_TABLE
FROM '\\path_to_network_directory\bulkinsert_test.txt'
WITH (
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
)
```

I get an error like this

> Cannot bulk load because the file
> "\path_to_network_directory\bulkinsert_test.txt" could not be opened.
> Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.).

Is this the problem with permissions or am I messing something with `BULK INSERT`?

---

Btw, in this case I cannot place the file at the computer where SQL Server is installed.

Comment: If I recall correctly, SQL Server will attempt to lock the file when it `BULK INSERT`s it, to stop the file changing while it is imported, which would require *write* permissions. If the domain user only has Read and Execute permissions, it won't be able to lock the file, as that requires write permissions. *I could be recalling incorrectly here though.*

Comment: @Larnu That makes a lot of sense. I recall when SQL Server refused to bulk insert an opened file. I told admins to change permissions and we'll see.

Comment: @Larnu This is not the case. Although the user has permissions to write the file, bulk insert still fails.

Comment: Are the permissions granted at **both** the Share and the file system levels? Also... it won't be able to open nor lock the file for reading if the file is currently open in Microsoft Excel or other Office programs that hold `FileShare.None` locks on files.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes,, the user has full-control permissions on both levels. The backup can be restored from the directory, but why `BULK INSERT` fails?